# How to redirect user to login page if not autheticated?

Tags: laravel

I have googled a lot about redirection if the user is not autheticated.
Most of them says to go App\Http\Middleware\Autheticated.php . In there the redirection route is setup.
in tutorial i see

```
//this method will be triggered before your controller constructor
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to login 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But in my case

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');  
        }
    }
```

if i replace redirecTo function with handle function then it gives me error about compatibility.

Also if i remove return route('login') in redirectTo function then it always redirect me to register page.

Comment: which route or which function you need to do this redirection ?

Comment: @Hamelraj In my Authenticate.php there is redirectTo(). Inside this function i want to redirect to login page.

Comment: try `return route('login');`   to change `return view('auth.login');`

Comment: @Hamelraj didn't work

Comment: then you are doing something wrong  maybe you have edited some default functions just try with new project and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made certian changes in ExceptionHander.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = Array($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
          case 'admin':
            $login = 'adminloginpage';
            break;
          case 'futsal':
            $login = 'futsalloginpage';
          break;  
          default:
            $login = 'register'; //i changed this to login
            break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

Because of this rediectTo function was overridden

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the Auth middleware in your routes, f.ex:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
   //Put inside this all the routes that you want to force the login
   Route::get('profile' , 'UserController@profile');
});
//Put outside this all the routes that you want to not force login
```

If a user want to access a route inside the middleware routing group without login, the middleware will redirect the user to the login page

Comment: Stil didn't work. It redirects me to the register page.

Comment: Try changing the redirectTo function from the Authenticate middleware class to the original: `protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    return route('login');
}`